# Is __MSDOS__ still defined when compiling with djgpp?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, djgpp

Is using `__MSDOS__` enough with djgpp or should `__DJGPP__` be used instead?

By comparison, I know `_WIN32` isn’t defined by default on cygwin *(based on the assumption djgpp and cygwin have the purpose to build an Unix layer to hide real OS details)*.

I no longer have a DOS machine to test it.

Comment: This is not a website where people read the manual of your compiler because you can't be bothered. Since most of us aren't writing DOS programs for our day job this is not something anyone is likely to know by heart. You will have to roll up your sleeves and RTFM.

Comment: Not sure, but https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/OperatingSystems/#msdos suggests there are multiple macros to test. I know Bruce's C compiler defines `__MSDOS__`. Maybe DJGPP does, but Turbo C uses one of the others (or vice versa)? [Another site](http://jesusnjim.com/programming/common-compiler-defines.html#djgpp) says yes. In the future, Google will save you some time: _<compiler/platform> predefined macros_.

Comment: @jforberg : I’m afraid http://www.delorie.com/djgpp doesn’t state it clearly. and binutils use both`__MSDOS__`and`__DJGPP__`

Comment: @ChronoKitsune : *(not related to the current question)* so according to [the site you found](https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/OperatingSystems/), you suggest that`_WIN32`isn’t defined on 16 bit in favor of`_WIN16`?

Comment: @user2284570 Yes, that's correct. [Microsoft confirms this briefly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff540443.aspx). That being said, I'm not sure why you'd want to target Win16 environments or any version of DOS...

Comment: If you are not targeting DOS why are you using DJGPP?

Comment: @MatteoItalia : I’m targeting security auditing in binutils source code *(check for path traversal)*.

Comment: you may get a DOS to test it with FreeDOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To list the predefined macros and their values, use

```
djgpp -E -x c -dM /dev/null
```